# What is the difference between goods yard, goods station and marshalling yard?

Tags: civil-engineering, rail

In railway engineering what is the difference between goods yard, goods station and marshalling yard?

Comment: what research have you done? ... why did your research fail?

Comment: Show the results of your research, that way we won't waste our time duplicating what you have already found.

Answer (score 0):

But then this is what some sources say

[image]

Comment: You've posted this in the Your Answer box. Is this an answer to your own question? Also you should post as text, not as a picture. Site rules require you to give attribution for the work of others.

Comment: it was to be a reply to fred. but as there is no option of sharing image in reply so posted as an answer

Comment: That doesn't work on SE sites. Answers float up and down by votes and user sorting preferences so any attempt to use it as a discussion board turns into a big mess. Two options: 1. Post a link to the article in a comment. 2. Add the reference material into your question. You might find the [Tour] helpful to understand how the site works.